# Position Div In Corner After Using Calc CSS Function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to position text after the calc function is activated & after hovering over an image,
like this example:

[image]

My code is this

```css
#wrapper-personalizado{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  min-height:40vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.layer{
  position: absolute;
  width:100vw;
  min-height: 40vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.layer .content-wrap{
  position: absolute;
  width:100vw;
  min-height: 40vw;
}

.layer .content-body{
  width:25%;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  color:#fff;
  z-index:1
}

.layer img{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.layer h1{
  font-size:2em;
}

.bottom{
  background:#222;
  z-index:1;
  transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.63, 0.04, 0.69, 1.01);
}

.bottom:hover ~ .top {
    width: calc(5vw + 1150px);
}

.bottom .content-body{
  right:5%;
  transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.63, 0.04, 0.69, 1.01);
}

.bottom:hover .content-body {
  right: 50%;
  transform: translateX(50%)
}

.bottom h1{
  color:#FDAB00;
}

.top{
  background:#eee;
  color:#222;
  z-index:2;
}

.top .content-body{
  left: 5%;
  transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.63, 0.04, 0.69, 1.01) 
}

.skewed .top{
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  margin-left:-1000px;
  width: calc(50vw + 1000px);
  border-right: 10px solid white;
  transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.63, 0.04, 0.69, 1.01) 
}

.skewed .top:hover {
  width: calc(105vw + 750px);
}

.skewed .top:hover .content-body {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}

.skewed .top .content-wrap{
  transform: skew(20deg);
  margin-left:1000px;
}

@media(max-width:1023px){
  
  body{
    font-size:75%;
  }
  
  .skewed{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="skewed flex" id="wrapper-personalizado">
        <div class="layer bottom" id="one">
            <div class="content-wrap">
                <div class="content-body">
                    <h1>AUTOMATIZACIÓN INDUSTRIAL</h1>
                    <a href="<?php echo the_field('boton_hero'); ?>" class="theme-btn">Conoce más</a>
                </div>
                <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/seamartini/seamartini1703/seamartini170300041/72903056-herramienta-de-trabajo-instrumento-y-equipo-para-la-construcción-y-la-reparación-de-patrón-de-trabajo-sin-pro.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="layer top" id="two">
            <div class="content-wrap">
                <div class="content-body">
                    <h1>MANEJO DE MATERIALES</h1>
                    <a href="<?php echo the_field('boton__hero_2'); ?>" class="theme-btn">Conoce más</a>
                </div>
                <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/donatas1205/donatas12051204/donatas1205120400043/13013042-carpintería-herramientas-de-construcción-de-hardware-debajo-de-la-tabla-de-madera.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

The effect I want to perform is like the one on this [page](https://www.emerson.com/en-us).

I am not a big fan of css and JS for the client side and it is difficult for me to know how to make those changes or effects.

Hope someone can help me

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin no, if the code that i put dosn't work you can check the result in here https://www.fgsaltillo.com/